# Heroku Parse Server & Mailgun with templates

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

Ive been trying to get Mailgun with templates working on my parse server currently running on Heroku.

At the moment I am running fine with **parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter**
which comes preinstalled in parse server.

However i am unsure on how to install parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template
or parse-server-mailgun which allow you to use HTML templates for emails...

On Heroku my files are sync'd from Dropbox and deployed. Could someone please give me a step by step guide on how to install and go about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

leveraging custom email adapter is done when you initialise ParseServer .
so in order to use **parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template** (for example) you need to do the following steps:

1. Open **index.js** file of your parse server project
2. Go to the line where ParseServer is being initialised. It should look like the following:

```js
var api = new ParseServer({
      databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db',
      cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
      ...
```

3. In terminal go to the folder where your parse server is installed and run the following command:

> npm install parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template --save

this will install the parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template module to your parse server app (by adding it to package.json and execute npm install)

4. Add a new object inside the constructor with the name of **emailAdapter**, specify the adapter that you want to use under module and then add all the relevant properties that this custom adapter expect to receive so for **parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template** it will be

```js
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'no-reply@yourdomain.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'mg.yourdomain.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv',

      // Verification email subject
      verificationSubject: 'Please verify your e-mail for %appname%',
      // Verification email body
      verificationBody: 'Hi,\n\nYou are being asked to confirm the e-mail address %email% with %appname%\n\nClick here to confirm it:\n%link%',
      //OPTIONAL (will send HTML version of email):
      verificationBodyHTML: fs.readFileSync("./verificationBody.html", "utf8") || null,

      // Password reset email subject
      passwordResetSubject: 'Password Reset Request for %appname%',
      // Password reset email body
      passwordResetBody: 'Hi,\n\nYou requested a password reset for %appname%.\n\nClick here to reset it:\n%link%',
      //OPTIONAL (will send HTML version of email):
      passwordResetBodyHTML: "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>........"
    }
  }
```

That's it. Now you can add your custom templates for email verification and password reset and sending emails .