# parse-server-mailgun configuration issue

Tags: node.js, npm, parse-server, mailgun

I am working on an iOS app using parse-server (/Heroku) as a back-end.
I would like to implement an email-confirmation system when a user creates an account, and also allow email recovery of lost passwords.

For that I want to use mailGun. I have installed the adapter by running:

```
npm install --save parse-server-mailgun
```

I have also added this to the ParseServer configuration block.

```
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailAdapter: {
    //module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
    //module: '@parse-server-mailgun',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'me@abc.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'something.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'mykey-mykey-mykey-mykey-mykey-mykey',
    }
  }
```

But it is not working. I don't know if I forgot some important step, other than the two above. Or if my configuration is wrong. I must admit I am not confident about the line above reading:

```
module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
```

Here is what I get when running the push:

```
git add . && git commit -m "update myapp" && git push heroku master

2018-03-08T09:03:3......0 app[api]: - Build started by user me
.....
2018-03-08T09:03:3......0 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-03-08T09:03:5......0 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-08T09:04:0......0 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
.....
2018-03-08T09:04:0......0 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2018-03-08T09:04:0......0 app[web.1]:undefined
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Config.js:174
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]:       throw 'An app name is required for e-mail verification and password resets.';
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: An app name is required for e-mail verification and password resets.
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script.
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely ...
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     ....-debug.log
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-08T09:04:1......0 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]: > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]:undefined
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Config.js:174
2018-03-08T09:04:2......0 app[web.1]:       throw 'An app name is required for e-mail verification and password resets.';
2018-03-08T09:04:22.996195+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-03-08T09:04:22.996197+00:00 app[web.1]: An app name is required for e-mail verification and password resets.
2018-03-08T09:04:23.011936+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-03-08T09:04:23.012286+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-03-08T09:04:23.013532+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
```

We can read *'An app name is required for e-mail verification and password resets.'* But I am not sure where to fix that.

Beside I need to clarify that the app is working as expected, before I get into trying to install this mailGun adapter.

Comment: its asking for 'appName'.... so in ur config , above 'verifyuseremails' , do you supply property 'appName'  ? ps to get MG to work in prod there is some additional work required on your hosting ( CNAME and stuff has to change ).

Comment: Indeed, if I add a line with an appName, things change; but I still have another issue: "Error: MailgunAdapter templates are not properly configured."

Comment: install the adapter  using node / npm .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090606/heroku-parse-server-mailgun-with-templates

Comment: Thanks. I was finally able to make progress and solve the problem, following this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-mailgun and then experimenting for the rest. I am now further down on the line tackling this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185967/parse-server-heroku-email-account-verification-not-working.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates appName property is not configured. It throws because the default email template references appName. There are two ways to configure appName:

1. If you start your parse-server with a config.json file, add it to the config.json like this:

```
config.json: { "allowClientClassCreation": false,
               ...    
               "appName": "my_app_name",   
               ...  
             }
```

2. Alternatively, set the appName with env variable:

```
PARSE_SERVER_APP_NAME="my_app_name"
```

references:

Your best guide is the code:

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/637326d3afcf82a4118f5ad5b316e6ae52fb5910/src/Options/Definitions.js

Documentation:

https://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/4.5.0/#email-verification-and-password-reset
https://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/master/ParseServerOptions.html