# Parse-server/Heroku email account verification not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server, pfuser, email-verification

I am trying to implement the email verification system on Parse-Server (/Heroku), when a user account is created; so that the user can confirm his/her account creation.

Things are working well for those matters:

- I can create a working account.
- The user receives the verification email that is expected.

The problem is this:

- When the user clicks on the link inside the verification email. This is what appears in the browser:

  {"error":"unauthorized"}

Has anyone seen a similar issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: sounds like a '401' on the link. u should be getting more info from your dev console ie devtools // network tab on google or the equivalent if you r on xcode. use your debug tools . set your debugger to 'halt on all errors' and u will see more details on the error in the tab in your version of developer tools

Comment: I will try to see if I can find indeed more information in the browser. But I am not following what you mean referring to Xcode. I am having this problem when I click the like I receive by mail. It has nothing to do with Xcode (as far as I know).

Comment: In the menu of FireFox, I can see inside Tools:
"Web Developer" and then "Web Console", if that is what you are talking about.
But not being into this kind of development, I don't know what I can do with it.
Even after taking a look, I don't know much more than before.

Comment: investigate the link and why its not valid. double check the other config properties that would affect the text used for the domain part of the email link ( 'host',  'home', linkback etc

Comment: I don't have control on any of that as fas as I know. This link is generated automatically when a user is created. I don't know what to check.